# Можно ли сделать с помощью css такую анимацию?

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, css-animation

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли  с помощью CSS сделать такую анимацию, чтобы некую выпуклость превратить в вогнутость ? Если да, то с помощью чего ?

Comment: Думаю что это возможно только в SVG.

Comment: посмотри [тут](http://waaark.com/), вроде что-то похожее

Comment: [http://shpargalkablog.ru/2011/03/css-povorot.html](http://shpargalkablog.ru/2011/03/css-povorot.html) Как вариант- просто повернуть на 180 градусов.

Comment: @Other ты был прав! только SVG

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Решение SVG

Реализовать кривую такой формы проще всего с помощью  Кривых Безье второго порядка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из рисунка выше видно, что можно получить последовательные кадры анимации, как у автора вопроса. Для этого надо изменять у параметра **Q** координаты **x1** и **y1**

Итак пишем несколько формул для нескольких патчей, составленных из квадратичных кривых Безье. [Теория здесь.](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=914#comm_Quadratic)

```html
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 version="1.1" width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="50 -50 300 300" style="border:1px solid red;" >
       
   <path d="M100,100 Q204,200 297,100" style="stroke:blue; stroke-width:3; fill:none;" /> 
   
   
   <path d="M100,100 Q204,167 297,100" style="stroke:blue; stroke-width:3; fill:none;" /> 
 
   
   <path d="M100,100 Q204,100 297,100" style="stroke:blue; stroke-width:3; fill:none;" />  
   
   <path d="M100,100 Q204,50 297,100" style="stroke:blue; stroke-width:3; fill:none;" /> 
   
   <path d="M100,100 Q204,20 297,100" style="stroke:blue; stroke-width:3; fill:none;" /> 
   
   
   <circle cx="100" cy="100"  r="6"  style="fill:none; stroke:orangered; stroke-width:3px;"  /> 
   <circle cx="297" cy="100"  r="6"  style="fill:none; stroke:orangered; stroke-width:3px;"  /> 
 
 </svg>
```

Для написания формул кривых Безье есть - [онлайн генератор](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1116)

На втором этапе делаем анимацию движения кривой, путем последовательного перебора всех кривых Безье.

```html
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 version="1.1" width="350px" height="300px" viewBox="0 50 300 350">
    <defs>
    <linearGradient id="LinGrad"
                    x1="0%" y1="0%"
                    x2="0%" y2="100%"
                    spreadMethod="pad">
      <stop offset="0%"   stop-color="dodgerblue" stop-opacity="1"/>
      <stop offset="75%" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="1"/>
   <stop offset="25%" stop-color="green" stop-opacity="1"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <rect x="10" y="10" width="350" height="350" rx="10" ry="10" transform="translate(50 0)" style="fill:url(#LinGrad); opacity:0.5;" />      

   
   <path d="M100,100 Q204,200 297,100" style="stroke:dodgerblue; stroke-width:3; fill:none;" > 
   
    <animate
      attributeName="d"
      dur="2s"
      repeatCount="3"
      values=
       "M100,100 Q204,200 297,100;
        M100,100 Q204,167 297,100;
        M100,100 Q204,100 297,100;
        M100,100 Q204,50 297,100;
        M100,100 Q204,20 297,100"/> 
    </path>
     
   <circle cx="100" cy="100"  r="6"  style="fill:none; stroke:orangered; stroke-width:3px;"  /> 
   <circle cx="297" cy="100"  r="6"  style="fill:none; stroke:orangered; stroke-width:3px;"  />  
   </svg>
```

Анимацию осуществляет команда

`animate attributeName="d" dur="2s"  repeatCount="3"`

в параметр **`values="M100,100 Q204,200 297,100;M100,100 Q204,167 297,100;`**

добавлены через точку с запятой все промежуточные положения квадратичной кривой Безье.

Ещё один [пример анимации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/647706/28748) квадратичных кривых Безье.

Answer (score 5):

### Благодаря анимации CSS свойства `transform`.

```css
div {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  animation-name: animation;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes animation {
  from { transform: none; }
  to { transform: rotateX(180deg); }
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

---

### C помощью двух блоков, CSS-анимаций и игрой с `border-radius`.

```css
div {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#top {
  animation-name: top;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
#bottom {
  animation-name: bottom;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
@keyframes top {
  from {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
  }
  to {
    border-radius: 0%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    height: 50px;
  }
}
@keyframes bottom {
  from {
    border-radius: 0%;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: -50px;
  }
  to {
    border-radius: 25%;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: -75px;
  }
  100% {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: -100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="top">
</div>

<div id="bottom">
</div>
```