# Анимация ссылки в формы "волны" на CSS

Tags: css, css3, анимация, svg, css-animation

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать примерно такую анимацию на CSS:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jxXFzbfud_w&feature=youtu.be
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ещё один вопрос по этой анимации: можно ли сделать так, чтобы буквы красились в определённый цвет при наведении волной?

Comment: Можно такое сделать на svg - так будет полегче. Иначе можно разбить каждую букву на 1 отдельный тег и при помощи препроцессоров (sass, к примеру) при помощи цикла задать таймаут для анимации каждой буквы. Вообщем, это реально, но запарно. Делать мне лень такое (:

Comment: к сожалению на css такое геморно делать, могу вам предложить такую библиотеку http://textillate.js.org/, посмотрите какие у нее есть эффекты, я видел там похожий и называется она bounce

Comment: @VostokSisters На SVG тоже подойдет. Но если не хотите - вас никто не заставляет. Просто спросил, возможно ли такое.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### SVG решение:

*Анимация начинается при наведении на ссылку*
Анимация основана на изменении атрибута `d` path
Промежуточные значения можно получить с помощью [онлайн генератора](http://svg-art.ru/?p=1116) квадратичных кривых Безье
Интересней выглядит в полно-экраном режиме.

```html
<style>
  svg {
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/hawaii-beach.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
  width:50%
  height:50%
  }
 </style>
  
 <svg   viewBox="0 0 650 500">
    
<defs> 
 <path id="Lsvg" d="M100 200Q200,200 300,200 T500,200" style="stroke:teal;fill-opacity:0.3;stroke-width:3;fill:none">
<animate begin="0.5s"  dur="10s" restart="whenNotActive"  attributeName="d" 
values="M100 200Q200,200 300,200 T500,200;
M100 200Q200,100 300,200 T500,200;
M100 200Q200,200 300,200 T500,200;
M100 200Q200,300 300,200 T500,200;
M100 200Q200,200 300,200 T500,200"/> 
</path>

</defs>
<text text-anchor="middle" font-size="25" fill="#026282">
  <textPath id="result" method="align" spacing="auto" startOffset="50%" xlink:href="#Lsvg"><tspan dy="-20">So easy to do with SVG just  few lines</tspan></textPath>
<animate
 begin="animLink.mouseover"
 dur="10s"
 repeatCount="1"
 attributeName="fill"
 values="red;green;red;green;red"/>
</text>
<use xlink:href="#Lsvg" transform="translate(0 -10)"/>
   
  <rect id="animLink" x="100" y="150" width="400" height="60" fill="#E0E0E0" fill-opacity="0.01" stroke="none" />  

    </svg>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Анимация с применением квадратичных кривых Безье подробно описана в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/647589/28748)  на вопрос «[Можно ли сделать с помощью css такую анимацию?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/582234/208074)» Прочтите, если появился интерес, и тогда будет легче понять, как тут работает анимация.